# How to setup RDS proxy to lambda in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, amazon-rds-proxy

I've already created the RDS proxy and wanted to attach something like this.

```
  provider:
  name: aws
  rds-proxy:
    arn: arn:aws:xxxxxx
```

Or any cloudformation syntax which I can extend in Resources section.